# How to display image in Data Cube in BIRT?

Tags: birt

I have a question regarding BIRT. I am trying to display an image inside a datacube, the image displayed should be related

for example in rows :

> ```
>    TEAM NAME              POINTS
> -------------------------------------
> team A / image A            5
> team B / image B            10
> team C / image C            15
> ```

I have followed the tuto here for a classic table and it works : http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/examples/reports/Image/Image.html (see here to get the rptdesign : http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/88-birt-image-example/)

Then, i tried it in a Datacube by adding the row ImageName as Dimensions in my cross tab but it's not working. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by dragging the "imageUrl" from my data set to the right of "team name" in the  data field.  Then I made "imageUrl" invisible from the property editor.  Then I set the value of it as a PGV from onCreate()

```
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("imageUrl", this.getValue())
```

Then add an image element under the "imageUrl" and use this script in the expression builder:

```
url = reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("imageUrl");
url;
```

This will have each team logo displayed to the right of the team name.